# Start with two activities Android application

Tags: android, xml, listview, android-activity, navigation-drawer

I am newbie Android 'developer'. I want to launch my application with two Activities: ListView (with optional slide up panel) and Navigation Drawer. I began my project from taking Navigation Drawer Activity and I modified it. Now, I want to add ListView but how to do it? I have tried to add this before android.support.design.widget.NavigationView in activity_main.xml but It doesn't work. Maybe should I add a new Activity in function onCreate in MainActivity class? Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: You can't have 2 activities on screen at the same time.  What you want are two fragments, or one activity with a much more complicated UI.

Comment: So, the best option is replace fragment with listview in function onCreate?

Comment: @drapek you are misunderstanding what an activity is, look for a tutorial  or follow the getting started tutorials from the Android docs.

Comment: you are already created an activity with navigation drawer then just add in the listview in xml and add data to it ,then it will appear